# Powershell - Interact with executable's command line prompts?

Tags: powershell, automation, expect

I need to automate some tasks against a legacy application. It doesn't have an API, but the vendor offers a .exe I can run to perform various tasks against the application.

I can call the .exe from within PowerShell just fine, but after calling it it prompts for the following input:

```
Do you agree to the license: YES
User name: myuid
Password: SuperSecretPassword`
```

I can run this interactively from the command prompt just fine and manually enter the requested input as prompted, but I need to automate this in a script.  The .exe doesn't accept any command line parameters for this either(it's an old app), the only parameters I can pass are the commands I want to execute against the application. The .exe is only command line based with no GUI, so GUI automation tools aren't an option either.

I could do this easily with `expect` in a *nix shell, however given that I have a .exe I need to run, that's out of the question. There doesn't appear to be an "expect" equivalent in Windows, so I'm curious if this can be accomplished in PowerShell?

Note: For Windows scripts I prefer PowerShell, but could utilize VBScript if necessary.

Comment: There is an Expect alternative on Windows now: https://github.com/zetamatta/expect (check the closed issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, if it's just one line you can pipe a string to an exe eg. `"asdf" | example.exe`, but it's multiple lines of input you might need to use SendKeys

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
$ID = (Start-Process example.exe -PassThru).id 
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic 
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate([Int32]$ID)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("YES~")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("myuid~")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("SuperSecretPassword~")
```

Comment: Negative.  Start-Process opens the command in a separate command prompt window, and then the SendKeys command sends the input to the PowerShell window that I launced it from.

Comment: I also tried it without using the Start-Process command, the executable ran, prompted me for the input.  I entered all inputs manually, the executable did it's thing, and when it was done the SendKeys commands output the 3 strings to the PowerShell prompt.

Comment: You might need to use `$ID = (Start-Process -PassThru).id` `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic`
`[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("$ID")`

Comment: That makes sense, but when I try it I get the following error: Exception calling "AppActivate" with "1" argument(s): "Process '14264' was not
found."  But what's intereseting, is if I open task manager on my computer and find the .exe, it's running under PID = 14264, so I'm not sure why PowerShell can't find it.

Comment: A little testing made me realize two issues with `AppActivate` first was that with the ID in quotes it was a string and the String overload looks for the window title. So we need to cast to an `Int32`. Second without a sleep, appactivate was going off before the window was ready.

Comment: Thank you!  that did it!