# How to send number 1 using powershell keystroke.

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Would you like to:
[1] Accept the certificate for this session
Please input your selection (The default selection is [1]): 1
I have to enter number one here, how it can be done through power shell script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - Interact with executable's command line prompts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852056/powershell-interact-with-executables-command-line-prompts)

Answer (score 0):

`Read-Host` would be the way to do it from the console while using Write-Host/Write-Output to present the option information.  You would of course need to check the contents of the variable to see if you got an expected result.

If you're looking for a simple yes/no answer and are OK with popups, use a .NET messagebox:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('message', 'titlemessage')
```

There are tons of overloads for this which include giving you the ability to control the buttons displayed and the icon (warning, error, informational, etc.)

EDIT:  This SO post shows how to accomplish SendKeys functionality with both a COM object and a .NET object:  [How to perform keystroke inside powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849522/how-to-perform-keystroke-inside-powershell)

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys(1)
```

and

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(1)
```

or

```
add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate(“Calc”)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“1{ADD}1=”)
```

from:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/10/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell/

Comment: I believe he is not asking for the script to prompt for that information, but for  the script to input that information into an executable.

Comment: Ah yes... I see that now.  He wants to interact with a prompt.  see edit.